# Is the Jiva completely dependent on Lord Vishnu for his protection?

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, vishishtadvaita

Is the Jiva completely helpless to protect himself and completely dependent on Lord Vishnu for his protection from any misforture, disaster or undesirable event?

If possible, please provide quotes/references from scriptures, acharya's teachings, reputed books or texts, etc.

Comment: Why vishishtadvaita tag?